# Separate webapps in Jetty on different ports

Tags: java, jetty

I need the following setup.

- Jetty must listen on port **8080** and **9090**
- Each port must have its own separate applications (i.e. **webapp1** runs on **8080** and **webapp2** on **9090**). The web-apps should only be accessible on their designated ports (i.e. **webapp2** must not! be available on port **8080**).

I have successfully added extra **connectors** to etc/jetty.xml so it now uses port 8080 and 9090. I have also added extra **handlers** so it now pick ups webaps from multiple directories (dir1/webapp1 and dir2/webapp2).

My problem is this: jetty deployes all webapps found by each handler to every connector (i.e. every port) and thus **webapp1** and **webapp2** both becomes accessible on port **8080** and **9090**.

I need a way to ensures that **handler1** (handles dir1/webapp1) is only designated to **connector1** (listens on port 8080) and equally for **connector2** to only pick up **handler2** (handles dir2/webapp2) on port **9090**.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jetty documentation shows two methods.](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/serving-webapp-from-particular-port.html)

The first configures two separate server instances, and starts them both by supplying the two configuration file names on the command line.

The second method uses names for the two connectors, and each application context names the connectors it will use.

Comment: I ended up with the 2nd (alternative) solution specified in the post you linked to as it was the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically going to create two instances in the same JVM.

Create two .xml files, and in each of the .xml files, specify:

```
...
<Set name="port">XXXX</Set>
...
<New id="webAppX"  class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">      
  <Arg><Ref id="Contexts"/></Arg>
  <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/X</Arg>
  <Arg>/webappX</Arg>
  ...
</New>
...
```

[make sure you replace the X values in the appropriate xml files.]

Start Jetty with two instances in the same JVM, like this:

```
java -jar start.jar webapp1.xml webapp2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two Jetty installations, if you want to separate the apps?

Comment: Jetty suggests that you can do this, "However, it is usually more efficient to run both Servers in the same JVM."